# Audio recorder not returning control to phonegap app

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova

Here's the code I'm using to capture the audio, this works perfectly, except on some specific devices:

```
device.capture.captureAudio(
    function (audioFiles) {
        // ** Never reaches here on certain devices **
    },
    logError,
    {limit:1}
);
```

When run on a Samsung Ace for example, the Audio recorder starts as usual, but control is not returned to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung's implementation of the Audio Recorder is broken. It never calls onActivityResult so we can't get the results of the recording. You'll have to use [Media.startRecord](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord) to work around this Samsung bloatware bug.